# What is a good, simple way to compute ISO 8601 week number?

Tags: java, date

Suppose I have a date, i.e. year, month and day, as integers. What's a good (correct), concise and fairly readable algorithm for computing the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [week number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) of the week the given date falls into? I have come across some truly horrendous code that makes me think surely there must be a better way.

I'm looking to do this in Java but psuedocode for any kind of object-oriented language is fine.

Answer (score 27):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2015 , 12 , 30 )
         .get ( 
             IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR 
         )
```

> 53

…or…

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.from (
    LocalDate.of( 2015 , 12 , 30 )
)
```

> 2015-W53

## java.time

Support for the [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) is now built into Java 8 and later, in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. Avoid the old and notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes as they have been supplanted by java.time.

These new java.time classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for date-only value without time-of-day or time zone. Note that you must specify a time zone to determine ‘today’ as the date is not simultaneously the same around the world.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
```

Or specify the year, month, and day-of-month as suggested in the Question.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( year , month , dayOfMonth );
```

The [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class provides info according to the ISO 8601 standard including the week-of-year for a week-based year.

```
int calendarYear = now.getYear();
int weekNumber = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekYear = now.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

Near the beginning/ending of a year, the week-based-year may be ±1 different than the calendar-year. For example, notice the difference between the Gregorian and ISO 8601 calendars for the end of 2015: Weeks 52 & 1 become 52 & 53.

[image]

[image]

## ThreeTen-Extra — `YearWeek`

The [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class represents both the ISO 8601 week-based year number *and* the week number together as a single object. This class is found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. The project adds functionality to the java.time classes built into Java.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.now( zoneId ) ;
```

Generate a `YearWeek` from a date.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from (
    LocalDate.of( 2015 , 12 , 30 )
)
```

This class can generate and parse strings in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = yw.toString() ;
```

> 2015-W53

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "2015-W53" ) ;
```

You can extract the week number or the week-based-year number.

```
int weekNumber = yw.getWeek() ;
int weekBasedYearNumber = yw.getYear() ;
```

You can generate a particular date (`LocalDate`) by specifying a desired day-of-week to be found within that week. To specify the day-of-week, use the `DayOfWeek` enum built into Java 8 and later.

```
LocalDate ld = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 13):

I believe you can use the Calendar object (just set FirstDayOfWeek to Monday and MinimalDaysInFirstWeek to 4 to get it to comply with ISO 8601) and call get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR).

Comment: Your reasoning and/or evidence being...?

Comment: Works most of the time, but not always. The Problem is described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net/) (yes, it is .Net-Code, but same Problem). See Basil Bourque answere for correct solution.

Answer (score 12):

```
/* Build a calendar suitable to extract ISO8601 week numbers
 * (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601_week_number) */
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

/* Set date */
calendar.setTime(date);

/* Get ISO8601 week number */
calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: In fact `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)` (at least half a week at year beginning), is default for the standard, and not needed in java - _I think_.

Comment: instead of `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)` use `calendar.getWeekYear()` to get week year consistent with ISO 8601

Comment: @JoopEggen That may be true sometimes, but not always, because `GregorianCalendar` is locale-sensitive. So depending on the selected locale (or default locale) the value for _minimal days in first week_ and also _first day of week_ can vary. The Javadoc of `GregorianCalendar` provides some information about this.

Comment: How do you get the date in your example? The timezone is not known if there is only year, month and day.

Answer (score 8):

The joda-time library has an ISO8601 calendar, and provides this functionality:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html

> yyyy-Www-dTHH:MM:SS.SSS This format of
>   ISO8601 has the following fields:
>
> ```
> * four digit weekyear, see rules below
> * two digit week of year, from 01 to 53
> * one digit day of week, from 1 to 7 where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday
> * two digit hour, from 00 to 23
> * two digit minute, from 00 to 59
> * two digit second, from 00 to 59
> * three decimal places for milliseconds if required
> ```
>
> Weeks are always complete, and the
>   first week of a year is the one that
>   includes the first Thursday of the
>   year. This definition can mean that
>   the first week of a year starts in the
>   previous year, and the last week
>   finishes in the next year. The
>   weekyear field is defined to refer to
>   the year that owns the week, which may
>   differ from the actual year.

The upshot of all that is, that you create a DateTime object, and call the rather confusingly (but logically) named getWeekOfWeekyear(), where a weekyear is the particular week-based definition of a year used by ISO8601.

In general, joda-time is a fantastically useful API, I've stopped using java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date entirely, except for when I need to interface with an API that uses them.

Answer (score 4):

Just the Java.util.Calendar can do the trick:
You can create a Calendar instance and set the **First Day Of the Week**
 and the **Minimal Days In First Week**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.setTime(date);

// Now you are ready to take the week of year.
calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

This is provided by the [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

> The week determination is compatible with the **ISO 8601** standard when
>   getFirstDayOfWeek() is MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4,
>   which values are used in locales where the standard is preferred.
>   These values can explicitly be set by calling setFirstDayOfWeek() and
>   setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek().

Comment: Good answer for those people who have access to neither the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework in Java 8+ nor the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. But otherwise, the old date-time classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar that were bundled with the earliest versions of Java should be avoided. The old classes are notoriously troublesome.

Comment: How do you get the date in your example? The timezone is not known if there is only year, month and day.

Answer (score 2):

The Calendar class almost works, but the ISO week-based year does not coincide with what an "Olson's Timezone package" compliant system reports. This example from a Linux box shows how a week-based year value (2009) can differ from the actual year (2010):

```
$ TZ=UTC /usr/bin/date --date="2010-01-01 12:34:56" "+%a %b %d %T %Z  %%Y=%Y,%%G=%G  %%W=%W,%%V=%V  %s"
Fri Jan 01 12:34:56 UTC  %Y=2010,%G=2009  %W=00,%V=53  1262349296
```

But Java's Calendar class still reports 2010, although the week of the year is correct. 
The Joda-Time classes mentioned by *skaffman* do handle this correctly:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(1262349296 * 1000L);
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));     // %V
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));             // %G

DateTime dt = new DateTime(1262349296 * 1000L);
System.out.println(dt.getWeekOfWeekyear());             // %V
System.out.println(dt.getWeekyear());                   // %G
```

Running that program shows:

> 53 2010 53 2009

So the ISO 8601 week number is correct from Calendar, but the week-based year is not.

The man page for strftime(3) reports:

> ```
>   %G     The ISO 8601 week-based year (see NOTES) with century as  a  decimal  number.   The
>          4-digit year corresponding to the ISO week number (see %V).  This has the same for‐
>          mat and value as %Y, except that if the ISO week number belongs to the previous  or
>          next year, that year is used instead. (TZ)
> ```

Comment: instead of `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)` use `cal.getWeekYear()` to get week year consistent with ISO 8601

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be on the bleeding edge, you can take [the latest drop of the JSR-310 codebase](http://www.threeten.org/) (Date Time API) which is led by Stephen Colebourne (of Joda Fame).  Its a fluent interface and is effectively a bottom up re-design of Joda.

Comment: FYI, JSR 310 is now implemented in Java 8 as the java.time package.

Answer (score -2):

this is the reverse: gives you the date of the monday of the week (in perl)

```
use POSIX qw(mktime);
use Time::localtime;

sub monday_of_week {
    my $year=shift;
    my $week=shift;
    my $p_date=shift;

    my $seconds_1_jan=mktime(0,0,0,1,0,$year-1900,0,0,0);
    my $t1=localtime($seconds_1_jan);
    my $seconds_for_week;
    if (@$t1[6] < 5) {
#first of january is a thursday (or below)
        $seconds_for_week=$seconds_1_jan+3600*24*(7*($week-1)-@$t1[6]+1);
    } else {
        $seconds_for_week=$seconds_1_jan+3600*24*(7*($week-1)-@$t1[6]+8);
    }
    my $wt=localtime($seconds_for_week);
    $$p_date=sprintf("%02d/%02d/%04d",@$wt[3],@$wt[4]+1,@$wt[5]+1900);
}
```