# Week of year calculation differences between Java and Python

Tags: java, python, calendar

I have two parts of my implementation, one in Python and one in Java. Now the problem is I realized their calculations of week number of the year don't match. For example:

Java code:

```
private static int getWeekOfYear(int y, int m, int d) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
    cal.set(y, m, d);
    return cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}

System.out.println(getWeekOfYear(2010, 7, 1));
```

Java result: `31`

Python code:

```
print datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0).isocalendar()[1]
```

Python result: `26`

Now how can I get these to be the same? I'd like Java to follow exactly python's calculation by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months in Java are 0-based, you need this:

```
cal.set(y, m - 1, d);
```

**EDIT:**

As noted by jarnbjo, `Calendar` should be configured to produce ISO 8601 week numbers [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147178/what-is-a-good-simple-way-to-compute-iso-8601-week-number):

```
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);    
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Comment: That is only the solution of a small part of the problem. See my response for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the odd month numbering in Java is not the entire solution. Java uses localized rules to calculate the week number (different countries have different rules regarding which weekday is the first and which week is the first of the year). Python's isocalendar function uses the week numbering rules according to ISO 8601, which for these purposes defines that a week starts on Monday and that January 4th is always in week number 1.

Comment: hi i accounted for this in "cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);", but made a mistake on the month. thanks for pointing this out anyway!

Comment: You must at least add cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY) as well to get the Java calendar to follow the ISO standard. But I am still not sure if you have to apply any further tweeks to get the Java calendar to be fully ISO compliant for the week numbering.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2010 , Month.JULY , 1 )
.get ( 
    IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR 
)
```

> 26

## Details

As other noted, your month argument was incorrect because of the crazy counting from zero done in that `Calendar` class.

Also noted was that `Calendar` class definition of "week" varies by `Locale` rather than using the [ISO 8601 standard week definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) used in your Python code.

## java.time

Another issue: You are using terribly troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest version of Java. They are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`. Use the handy [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum for readability.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2010 , Month.JULY , 1 ) ;
```

Or use month number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2010 , 7 , 1 ) ;
```

Calculate the standard [ISO 8601 week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Use the [`LocalDate::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#get(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)) method to access a relevant value. Pass the enum element [`IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html#WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR) to indicate your desired value.

```
int w = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

## `YearWeek`

Tip: If you are doing much work with this week-of-year, you may find helpful the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( ld ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check the javadoc for the `set` method.  You'll see the following:

> Parameters:
>
> year - the value used to set the YEAR
>   calendar field.
>
> month - the value used to set the
>   MONTH calendar field. Month value is
>   0-based. e.g., 0 for January.
>
> date - the value used to set the
>   DAY_OF_MONTH calendar field.

So your code should become the following:

```
private static int getWeekOfYear(int y, int m, int d) {     
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
    cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);     
    cal.set(y, m - 1, d);     // Note the change here
    return cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java `7` is not July, it's August.