# Set the first week of specific year PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I wanted to set one date to the `first week of the year` that i would pass to a function as argument. I mean if my date is `03/18/2015` and i wish to set this date to the first week of the year the result should be: `12/31/2014` (this is the first week of the first date [03/18/2015] ). This is the code im trying but when change the year of the date gives me one previous or the next week of the first week of year:

```
$actualDate = new DateTime("03/18/2015");
$actualDate = setFirstWeekOfYear($actualDate);

function setFirstWeekOfYear( $currentDate )
{
    // this variable will contain the current week number
    $currentWeek = $currentDate->format("W");

    // Get the current year (2015 in this moment)
    $currentYear = $currentDate->format("Y");

    // Rest the weeks number to the current date
    $currentDate = $currentDate->modify("-{$currentWeek} week");

    return $currentDate;
}

// 03/18/2017 => the output is 12/31/2016
// 03/18/2015 => the output should be 12/31/2014 but what i'm getting is 12/24/2014
```

Note: with the date 03/18/2017 works well but with 03/18/2015 is giving me one week previous to the first week of the year. I'm taking java `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1` function as reference

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That is the same day of the last week of the previous year which is what your code should produce. Now, do you want the last week of the year? Or last calender day of the year?

Comment: i wanted the first week of the year, im trying to reproduce the same java code to php: in java you make: `Calendar workingCal = Calendar.getInstance(); System.out.println("Previous WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + workingCal.getTime()); workingCal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
       System.out.println("WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + workingCal.getTime());`. The first output is the original date and the second is with the first week of year

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime class understands ISO week numbering, so you can do something like this:-

```
function getFirstWeekOfYear(\DateTime $date = null)
{
    if(!$date){
        $date = new \DateTime();
    }
    return (new \DateTime())->setISODate((int)$date->format('o'), 1, $date->format('w'));
}
```

You should note that the ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is **the week with the year's first Thursday in it**<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)</sup>.

[A working example](http://3v4l.org/pmgZF).

1: [ISO week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)
2: [PHP date format strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

I am not a Java programmer, but a quick bit of googling suggests to me that Java does not use ISO week numbers, so **may** be giving you the wrong result. [This question and answers may help you further.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147178/what-is-a-good-simple-way-to-compute-iso-8601-week-number)

Comment: i know that the logic of the first week of the year is something wrong, but java does it with the calendar class :|, the example show the first week of the next year not the current one

Comment: Sorry, my mistake using copy pasted code from a project. See my edits and the corrected example.

Comment: When i replace the date for `2017-03-18` it returns `2017-01-07`, it should return `12/31/2016` instead

Comment: Why do you expect it to return that? That is Saturday of the last week of 2016, week 1 of 2017 starts on Sunday 1st Jan.

Comment: Once again, Java give me that result, i know logically this is wrong but the goal is make the output as same as Java does. This is the Java Code: `Calendar workingCal = Calendar.getInstance(); System.out.println("Previous WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + workingCal.getTime()); workingCal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1); System.out.println("WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + workingCal.getTime());`

Comment: See my edit, sorry I can't help further, but my Java knowledge is minimal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have the php code that makes the magic i will post the answer to help someone else having this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

By doing some tests on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ ... I found that if you did:

```
$currentWeek = $currentDate->format("W") - 1; // subtract 1
```

that would produce the 31st as the date ... I think the reasoning has to do with the fact that you **don't want to include** the current week of the `$actualDate`. EG: If March 18, 2015 = the 12th week ... subtract 11 weeks before the 12th week.

Try it out, maybe that'll work for you?

---

### UPDATE (Revised)

---

Look at the comments for an explanation:

```
$actualDate = new DateTime("03/18/2016");
$actualDate = setFirstWeekOfYear($actualDate);

function setFirstWeekOfYear($currentDate)
{
  // Grab year of current date
  $currentYear = $currentDate->format("Y");

  // Make a new DateTime variable and set the date
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date->setISODate($currentYear, 1, -1);

  // This should give you the Monday of the
  // first week that the year starts on
  return $date;
}

// 03/19/2018 = Saturday, December 30, 2017
// 03/19/2017 = Saturday, December 31, 2016
// 03/19/2016 = Saturday, January 02, 2016
// 03/19/2015 = Saturday, December 27, 2014
// 03/19/2014 = Saturday, December 28, 2013
echo $actualDate->format("l, F d, Y");
```

Comment: the problem is that sometimes i dont need to substract days to get the correct value

Comment: So what **day** of the first week of the year do you need?

Comment: Is not about specific day is about week, the first week of year should set automatically the day

Comment: Java function that get the magic: `Calendar workingCal = Calendar.getInstance(); System.out.println("Previous WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + workingCal.getTime()); workingCal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1); System.out.println("WEEK_OF_YEAR: " + workingCal.getTime());`

Comment: Did you take a look at my update? Can you try that out?

Comment: I tried but when i put "03/19/2016" the ouput is: "12/26/2016". Instead in java i get this result: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2a0jh2v.jpg

Comment: I notice you've found something but I've updated my answer in case you wanted to take a look :)