# How does oracle sql's to_date and iw work internally

Tags: java, oracle

The following sql is to calculate the week number of 20811231, the result is 1, which means 20181231's year week is 201901

```
select to_number(to_char(to_date('20181231','YYYYMMDD'), 'iw')) from dual
```

What I am doing now is to write a java method that does the same thing as the above sql: input 20181231, the method will output 1,and for other inputs, the output should also be the same.

I want to ask how I can achieve this using java.util.Calendar class

Comment: See [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Note: this class is NOT thread-safe

Comment: Being very picky... the title refers to `to_date()`, but `iw` isn't a valid format model for that function; you're really asking about `to_char()`.

Comment: `LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 31).get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear())` will give you `53` and `LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 31).get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear())` will give you `1`. So it depends, whether you're looking for the "week of week-based year" or "week of year".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format `IW` means week number according [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

However I strongly assume there is a build-in function in Java, you don't have to code it by yourself.

Have a look at [What is a good, simple way to compute ISO 8601 week number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147178/what-is-a-good-simple-way-to-compute-iso-8601-week-number)